# Impossible lookbehind with a backreference

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

From my understanding,

```
(.)(?<!\1)
```

should never match. Actually, php's `preg_replace` even refuses to compile this and so does ruby's `gsub`. The python `re` module seems to have a different opinion though:

```
import re
test = 'xAAAAAyBBBBz'
print (re.sub(r'(.)(?<!\1)', r'(\g<0>)', test))
```

Result:

```
(x)AAAA(A)(y)BBB(B)(z)
```

Can anyone provide a reasonable explanation for this behavior?

## Update

This behavior appears to be [a limitation](http://bugs.python.org/issue814253) in the `re` module. The alternative [`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module seems to handle groups in assertions correctly:

```
import regex

test = 'xAAAAAyBBBBz'

print (regex.sub(r'(.)(?<!\1)', r'(\g<0>)', test))
## xAAAAAyBBBBz

print (regex.sub(r'(.)(.)(?<!\1)', r'(\g<0>)', test))
## (xA)AAA(Ay)BBB(Bz)
```

Note that unlike `pcre`, `regex` also allows variable-width lookbehinds:

```
print (regex.sub(r'(.)(?<![A-Z]+)', r'(\g<0>)', test))
## (x)AAAAA(y)BBBB(z)
```

Eventually, `regex` is going to be included in the standard library, as mentioned in [PEP 411](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0411/#candidates-for-provisional-inclusion-into-the-standard-library).

Comment: It's matching as if you used `(.)(?!\1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does look like a limitation (nice way of saying "bug", as I learned from a support call with Microsoft) in the Python `re` module.

I guess it has to do with the fact that Python does not support variable-length lookbehind assertions, but it's not clever enough to figure out that `\1` will always be fixed-length. Why it doesn't complain about this when compiling the regex, I can't say.

Funnily enough:

```
>>> print (re.sub(r'.(?<!\0)', r'(\g<0>)', test))
(x)(A)(A)(A)(A)(A)(y)(B)(B)(B)(B)(z)
>>>
>>> re.compile(r'(.*)(?<!\1)') # This should trigger an error but doesn't!
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x00000000026A89C0>
```

So better don't use backreferences in lookbehind assertions in Python. Positive lookbehind isn't much better (it also matches here as if it was a positive lookahead):

```
>>> print (re.sub(r'(.)(?<=\1)', r'(\g<0>)', test))
x(A)(A)(A)(A)Ay(B)(B)(B)Bz
```

And I can't even guess what's going on here:

```
>>> print (re.sub(r'(.+)(?<=\1)', r'(\g<0>)', test))
x(AA)(A)(A)Ay(BB)(B)Bz
```

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my feelings about this being a bug.

Comment: Python is apparently not the only language that has problems with backreference in lookbehind assertions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734977/backreferences-in-lookbehind/2735611#2735611