# regexp for extracting years

Tags: python, regex

Given a string, how do I extract all sequences of **exactly** 4 digits?

That is, for `1234 12 12345 1bc5 9876` I want to get `[1234, 9876]`.

I got as far as `re.findall('\D\d\d\d\d\D')`, but that fails on text boundaries (when there's no character before/after a match).

---

Solution preferably using Python 2.7, but I guess this is pretty general, any language will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general answer is surprisingly complicated, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319696/match-exactly-n-repetitions-of-the-same-character) for more info. However in this particular case, we can simply use a word-boundary assertion `\b`:

```
re.findall(r'\b\d{4}\b', ....)
```