# Counting Instances of Consecutive Duplicate Letters in a Python String

Tags: python, string, algorithm, count

I'm trying to figure out how I can count the number of letters in a string that occur 3 times. The string is from `raw_input()`.

For example, if my input is:

```
abceeedtyooo
```

The output should be: 2

This is my current code:

```
print 'Enter String:'
x = str(raw_input (""))

print  x.count(x[0]*3)
```

Comment: You've explained what you're trying to do, but not what your specific question is. Are you getting an exception? Bad results? Exploding computer screen?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: We can still help you if it is a homework problem, but you've got to give us some details to walk you through to a solution instead of just giving you the answer.

Comment: Do you want to count *consecutive* duplicates as in your example?

Comment: yes thats what im tyring to do count how many 3 consecutive duplicates in the string

Comment: related: [Python - how to remove duplicates only if consecutive in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11460855/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the chars in the string, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter("abceeedtyooo")
>>> print(counter)
Counter({'e': 3, 'o': 3, 'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'y': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 't': 1})
```

Then you can filter the result as follows:

```
>>> result = [char for char in counter if counter[char] == 3]
>>> print(result)
['e', 'o']
```

If you want to match *consecutive* characters only, you can use regex (cf. [`re`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html)):

```
>>> import re
>>> result = re.findall(r"(.)\1\1", "abceeedtyooo")
>>> print(result)
['e', 'o']
>>> result = re.findall(r"(.)\1\1", "abcaaa")
>>> print(result)
['a']
```

This will also match if the same character appears three consecutive times multiple times (e.g. on `"aaabcaaa"`, it will match `'a'` twice). Matches are non-overlapping, so on `"aaaa"` it will only match once, but on `"aaaaaa"` it will match twice. Should you not want multiple matches on consecutive strings, modify the regex to `r"(.)\1\1(?!\1)"`. To avoid matching *any* chars that appear *more* than 3 consecutive times, [use `(.)(?<!(?=\1)..)\1{2}(?!\1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319696/match-exactly-n-repetitions-of-the-same-character). This works around a problem with Python's regex module that cannot handle `(?<!\1)`.

Comment: i used this and yes it prints out the letters with 3 consecutive 
duplicates, 
so how do i count the result
in this case its "e" and 'o' i want to count them that with give me the output of '2'

so for example i have aaabbbccc:
the count will be: 3

Comment: Use `len` to find the length of the result list: `print(len(result))` should output `2`.

Comment: why is it that there are some cases of letter combination that it fails to count for example my string is:abcaaa 
the result is 0

Comment: Because `a` appears 4 times. I'm going to add something for 3 *consecutive* chars...

Comment: sorry forgot to confirm this :)
your awesome, 
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To count number of consecutive duplicate letters that occur exactly 3 times:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> sum(len(list(dups)) == 3 for _, dups in groupby("abceeedtyooo"))
2
```

Answer (score 1):

**We can count the chars in the string through 'for' loop**

```
s="abbbaaaaaaccdaaab"
st=[]
count=0
for i in set(s):
    print(i+str(s.count(i)),end='')
```

`Output: a10c2b4d1`