# Using Regex to find words with characters that are the same or that are different

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words such as:

```
l = """abca
bcab
aaba
cccc
cbac
babb
"""
```

I want to find the words that have the same first and last character, and that the two middle characters are different from the first/last character.

The desired final result:

```
['abca', 'bcab', 'cbac']
```

I tried this:

```
re.findall('^(.)..\\1$', l, re.MULTILINE)
```

But it returns all of the unwanted words as well.
I thought of using [^...] somehow, but I couldn't figure it out.
There's a way of doing this with sets (to filter the results from the search above), but I'm looking for a regex.

Is it possible?

Comment: ".*" is a fine regex to find characters that are the same or different. :)

Comment: You have seven answers all of which answer your question (although two of them say "this is better done by other means than regexes", with which I'm inclined to agree). You should accept one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** fixed to use negative *lookahead* assertions instead of negative *lookbehind* assertions. Read comments for @AlanMoore and @bukzor explanations.

```
>>> [s for s in l.splitlines() if re.search(r'^(.)(?!\1).(?!\1).\1$', s)]
['abca', 'bcab', 'cbac']
```

The solution uses *negative lookahead assertions* which means 'match the current position only if it isn't followed by a match for something else.' Now, take a look at the lookahead assertion - `(?!\1)`. All this means is 'match the current character only if it isn't followed by the first character.'

Comment: You should explain what this does, since not everyone knows regex lookaround semantics.

Comment: spinlok: you seem to be asserting that the first group doesn't match \1, which seems impossible: `(.)(?<!\1)`. I believe you mean to use a negative *look-ahead* assertion `(?!)`, which is more efficient anyway.

Comment: As a matter of fact, backreferences are illegal in lookbehinds.  Did you actually test this?  But @bukzor is right, it works if you change the lookbehinds to lookaheads.

Comment: @AlanMoore, yeah I tested it - copied it straight from my bpython shell. Can you provide a reference for your claim that backreferences are illegal in lookbehinds?

Comment: Not specifically, but regex engines have to treat backreferences as variable-length constructs, and that means they can't be used in lookbehinds (except in .NET and JGSoft, of course).  Python *should* flag it as an error when the regex is compiled; that fact that it doesn't is a bug, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279055/impossible-lookbehind-with-a-backreference).

Comment: By the way, shouldn't those lookbehinds come *after* the dots, like this? `.(?<!\1).(?<!\1)`  The way you have it, the first lookbehind seems to be asserting that the capturing group didn't really match what it just matched. ;) Anyway, I've tried your regex in several online, Python-powered regex testers, and it doesn't work in any of them.

Comment: @AlanMoore: I have all the same objections, but it *does* seem to work, inexplicably.

Comment: @AlanMoore and bukzor, my logic here is that the first lookbehind applies to the second character. See this example from the python docs: 

    `>>> m = re.search('(?<=-)\w+', 'spam-egg')`
    `>>> m.group(0)`
    `'egg'`

Comment: But *your* first lookbehind is looking at the *first* character--or should be.  Instead, it seems to be acting as if the `\1` has zero length, so it backs up zero positions and tries to match something that isn't the same as `\1`.  Since it's really looking at the *second* character, it can succeed if that's not the same as the first character.  As a commenter said in the other Q/A I linked to, it's acting just like the lookahead `(?!\1)` would.  Your regex is only working by accident; if you change those lookbehinds to lookaheads it will work because it's correct.

Comment: @AlanMoore, thanks for the explanation! I've fixed the regex to use lookaheads instead.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here's probably the simplest:

```
re.findall(r'''
           \b          #The beginning of a word (a word boundary)
           ([a-z])     #One letter
           (?!\w*\1\B) #The rest of this word may not contain the starting letter except at the end of the word
           [a-z]*      #Any number of other letters
           \1          #The starting letter we captured in step 2
           \b          #The end of the word (another word boundary)
           ''', l, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
```

If you want, you can loosen the requirements a bit by replacing `[a-z]` with `\w`. That will allow numbers and underscores as well as letters. You can also restrict it to 4-character words by changing the last `*` in the pattern to `{2}`.

Note also that I'm not very familiar with Python, so I'm assuming your usage of `findall` is correct.

Comment: -1 the OP has already tried something similar and found it inadequate; you've missed the requirement that the middle letters should *not* match the beginning/ending.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - You're right, I did miss that part. My mistake. I've edited the pattern to account for that.

Comment: You'd do him a service by demonstrating the re.VERBOSE flag. It'd also make your answer shorter.

Comment: @bukzor - Good call. As I said, I'm not too familiar with Python, so please let me know if I got the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To heck with regexes.

```
[
    word
    for word in words.split('\n')
    if word[0] == word[-1]
    and word[0] not in word[1:-1]
]
```

Comment: The `any()` is a little overkill. `word[0] in word[1:-1]` has the same effect.

Comment: Er, yes, let me fix that, that was dumb. Simple is better than complex :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you required to use regexes? This is a much more pythonic way to do the same thing:

```
l = """abca
bcab
aaba
cccc
cbac
babb
"""

for word in l.split():
  if word[-1] == word[0] and word[0] not in word[1:-1]:
     print word
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
result = re.findall(r"\b([a-z])(?:(?!\1)[a-z]){2}\1\b", subject)
```

This is similar to Justin's answer, except where that one does a one-time lookahead, this one checks each letter as it's consumed.

```
\b
([a-z])  # Capture the first letter.
(?:
  (?!\1)   # Unless it's the same as the first letter...
  [a-z]    # ...consume another letter.
){2}
\1
\b
```

I don't know what your real data looks like, so chose `[a-z]` arbitrarily because it works with your sample data.  I limited the length to four characters for the same reason.  As with Justin's answer, you may want to change the `{2}` to `*`, `+` or some other quantifier.

Comment: This is an interesting twist. +1. Any reason you prefer this version other than clarity/brevity?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with negative lookahead or lookbehind assertions; see http://docs.python.org/library/re.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Python guru, but maybe this

```
re.findall('^(.)(?:(?!\1).)*\1$', l, re.MULTILINE)
```

expanded (use multi-line modifier):

```
^                # begin of line
  (.)            # capture grp 1, any char except newline
  (?:            # grouping
     (?!\1)         # Lookahead assertion, not what was in capture group 1 (backref to 1)
     .              # this is ok, grab any char except newline
  )*             # end grouping, do 0 or more times (could force length with {2} instead of *)
  \1             # backref to group 1, this character must be the same
$                # end of line
```