# Java regex error - Look-behind with group reference

Tags: java, regex, backreference, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to build a regex that matches exactly two occurrences of a char in a class. This is the regex I made:

```
(?<!\1)([^raol1c])\1(?!\1)
```

As you can see, it uses negatives look-aheads and behind. But, as usual the latter does not work; java throws the well-known exception "look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length" when it clearly has a maximum length (exactly one char).

Ideally the regex should match "hh", "jhh", "ahh", "hhj", "hha" but not "hhh".

Any ideas about how to deal with this and make a workaround?

Comment: Is there a set length for the strings you are checking?

Comment: No, strings could be of any length.

Comment: I don't understand your rule: should `"hhaa"` match?

Comment: Yes. Because the regex match "hh" then look ahead for a negative match of "h" and looks behind for a negative match of "h" what is true in both cases.

Comment: For a really simple workaround beyond a single regex, search for `([^raol1c])\1+` and check that the result is not more than two characters long.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backreferences in lookbehind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734977/backreferences-in-lookbehind)

Comment: Note that even if backreferences could be directly used inside lookbehinds, this regex would not work, because at the time `(?<!\1)` would be evaluated, `\1` is not yet captured. It would need to be `([^raol1c])(?<!\1.)\1(?!\1)`, which does work in PCRE2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a workaround. It's ugly but apparently it works:

```
(?<!(?=\1).)([^raol1c])\1(?!\1)
```

Putting the backreference into a zero-length lookahead inside the lookbehind makes the lookbehind certainly of fixed length.

Disclaimer, I did not come up with this (unfortunately): [Backreferences in lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734977/backreferences-in-lookbehind)

**EDIT:**

The above pattern does not rule out `hhh` for some reason. However, this works:

```
(?<!(.)(?=\1))([^raol1c])\2(?!\2)
```

If we create the first group inside the lookbehind then we can use this to ensure that the first character after the lookbehind is not the same as the one before it.

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/17J8nL)

Comment: Good one. To use with Matcher.matches().

Comment: The code `Pattern.compile("(?<!(?=\\1).)([^raol1c])\\1(?!\\1)").matcher("hhh").find()` returns `true` but should be `false`. It also returns `true` with "hh".

Comment: @user2402372 I've got a working version. Edit coming in a second.

Comment: This can be golfed down by 1 character: `([^raol1c])(?<!(?=\1)..)\1(?!\1)`