# Censoring selected words (replacing them with ****) using a single replaceAll?

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to censor some words in a string by replacing each character in the word with a "*". Basically I would want to do

```
String s = "lorem ipsum dolor sit";
s = s.replaceAll("ipsum|sit", $0.length() number of *));
```

so that the resulting `s` equals `"lorem ***** dolor ***"`.

I know how to do this with repeated `replaceAll` invokations, but I'm wondering, **is this possible to do with a single `replaceAll`?**

---

Update: It's a part of a research case-study and the reason is basically that I would like to get away with a one-liner as it simplifies the generated bytecode a bit. It's not for a serious webpage or anything.

Comment: I foresee a "Scunthorpe problem" in your future. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: yeah, don't make the clbuttic mistakes

Comment: and avoid this:  http://www.alanbaxteronline.com/2008/07/01/homosexual-wins-100m.html

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628534/codingbat-plusout-using-regex

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Aah, `Pattern.quote(word)` nice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a modification to aioobe's answer, using nested assertions instead of nested loop to generate the assertions:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String s = "lorem ipsum dolor sit blah $10 bleh";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(censorWords("ipsum", "sit", "$10"), "*"));
    // prints "lorem ***** dolor *** blah *** bleh"
}
public static String censorWords(String... words) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String w : words) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append("|");
        sb.append(
           String.format("(?<=(?=%s).{0,%d}).",
              Pattern.quote(w),
              w.length()-1
           )
        );
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Some key points:

- `StringBuilder.append` in a loop instead of `String +=`
- `Pattern.quote` to escape any `$` or `\` in censored words

That said, this is not the best solution to the problem. It's just a fun regex game to play, really.

#### Related questions

- [codingBat plusOut using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628534/codingbat-plusout-using-regex)

---

#### How it works

We want to replace with `"*"`, so we have to match one character at a time. The question is which character.

It's the character where if you go back long enough, and then you look forward, you see a censored word.

Here's the regex in more abstract form:

```
(?<=(?=something).{0,N})
```

This matches positions where, allowing you to go back up to `N` characters, you can lookahead and see `something`.

Comment: Beautiful! Would you care to break it a part and elaborate a bit? (The regexp I mean.)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible using [zero-width lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String s = "lorem ipsum dolor sit";
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll(censorWords("ipsum", "sit"), "*"));
    }

    public static String censorWords(String... words) {
        String re = "";
        for (String w : words)
            for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++)
                re += String.format("|((?<=%s)%s(?=%s))",
                        w.substring(0, i), w.charAt(i), w.substring(i + 1));
        return re.substring(1);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
lorem ***** dolor ***
```

The generated regular expression isn't pretty but it does the trick :-)

Comment: Hehe.. @polygenelubricants, *you* taught me look-arounds! :-) (I know the resulting expression is ugly as hell, and that it's probably an extremely inefficient solution :)

Comment: see my answer; it's a slight mod to your answer. It was taught to me by Alan Moore.

Comment: you can change it to  re += String.format("|(?i)((?<=%s)%s(?=%s))",   if you want the ignored case too

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good way to censor text.  Jeff Atwood has a great post about censoring in this way.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

Unless you are going to spend lots and lots of time on this censoring feature it will probably end up censoring things that shouldn't be.

**Another note:**
Making the Java code into a 1-liner will not necessarily simplify the bytecode.  Using that logic, you could throw your censoring code into a single method and then just use that.

Comment: It's a part of a case-study for a research project, and the reason is basically that I would like to have a simple one-liner as it simplifies the generated bytecode a bit.

Comment: @aioobe Well, is it completely necessary to censor the document?  Can you just do it by hand?

Comment: It's not a document, it's a part of a "dummy" chat server. As I said, nothing serious, just a part of a basic case-study in data-flow analysis.

Comment: @aioobe I added a bit to my answer on the end you may wanna look at.

Answer (score 2):

Java's replace method doesn't take a callback as argument; so it isn't easy. But since profanity filters are mostly used on the web, I assume you can use JavaScript for that.

```
var s = "this is some sample text to play with";
var r = s.replace(/\b(some|sample|to)\b/g, function() {
  var star = "*";
  var len = arguments[1].length;
  while(--len)
    star += "*";
  return star;
});
console.log(r);//this is **** ****** text ** play with
```

Comment: Nice solution. Basically something like that I'm after. Unfortunately it's not a web-application and javascript is not involved :-/

Comment: I figured it out myself, using java (see the answer I posted). But thanks for your suggestion!