# Is there something like PHP's preg_replace_callback() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want to do is `str.replace(pattern, callback)`,

not simply `str.replace(pattern, replace_pattern)`,

is it possible to do it in javascript?

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966172/censoring-selected-words-replacing-them-with-using-a-single-replaceall/2966273#2966273

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why, yes, you can do exactly that: `str.replace(pattern, function () { ... })`.

Here's some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement

Comment: Hi, seems good but not solves in the case of `g` regex: no ["array group" here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) at guide... How to supply the function with the arbitrary array of `RegExp('\{([^\}]*)\}', 'g')`? (imagine the case of URI-template resolution by regex).

Answer (score 7):

Yes

```
var s2 = s1.replace(/regex/, function(whole, part1, part2, ...) { ... })
```

The function is passed the whole matched string as the first argument. If there are any capturing groups, those are passed as subsequent arguments.

Comment: But how to get the full array for an arbitrary set of parts?

Comment: @PeterKrauss as in any function, the complete set of actual parameters passed are available in the `arguments` array-like object.

Comment: No ["array group" here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) , the last are `offset` and  `string`, and you need an a prioru knowledge about number of matched itens. Look, I am talking about `g` option in a regular expression... Example `RegExp('\{([^\}]*)\}', 'g')` for an URI template string.

Comment: OK, well I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: thanks, check my loop solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63108491/287948)

Answer (score 0):

The general case have no solution with `s1.replace(/regex/, function(whole, part1, part2, ...partN) { ... })`,  where you need to know all parts and it is not valid `g` option;

### arbitrary number of itens

The example of `RegExp('\{([^\}]*)\}', 'g')` can be solved by a loop... Supposing the  URI-template problem, replacing each placeholder by global  `getData` dictionary.

```js
const tpl = 'myEtc/{aa}/etc1/{bb}/etc2'
const getData = {"aa":"expandAA","bb":"expandBB"}

function expandTpl(getData,s0){  // s0 is the link_template_input
  const r = RegExp('\{([^\}]*)\}', 'g');
  let s = '';
  let idx=0
  for (let a; (a=r.exec(s0)) !== null;) {
    s   += ( s0.substring(idx, r.lastIndex-a[0].length) + getData[a[1]] )
    idx = r.lastIndex
  }
  if ( idx<s0.length ) s += s0.substring(idx,s0.length)
  return s
}

console.log( tpl )
console.log( expandTpl(getData,tpl) )
```