# JAVA replace all but variable string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

This is my first post. I have problem with String in Java. I want to use regular expression. Thank you in advance for any help.

My String is:

```
String str = "abXYxyzXYZabXasdfggXYZ".
```

I want to replace all characters with "+" but not variable below:

```
String word = "XYZ"
```

So the output should be like that:

```
+++++++XYZ+++++++++XYZ.
```

I started out with:

```
str.replaceAll("[^" + word + "]", "+")
```

But I got different output like that:

```
++XY+++XYZ++X++++++XYZ
```

Comment: `java.util.regex` does not support a construct that matches any text other than a certain *multicharacter* string of text. Almost all regex flavors do not support it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codingBat plusOut using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628534/codingbat-plusout-using-regex)

Comment: That is because `[...]` in regex denotes a **set of single characters**. You can't that easily denote the inverse of whole words. So `[^XYZ]` matches every character that is not `X`, not `Y` and not `Z`, so the whole alphabet except `X, Y, Z`. It does **not** match whole words that are unequal to the word `XYZ`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negating a set of words via java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333540/negating-a-set-of-words-via-java-regex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Brief

This *can* actually be accomplished. It's an interesting approach since Java doesn't allow regex *If* clauses, but you can actually use a combination of lookaheads and lookbehinds within a negative lookahead to *mimic* a sort of *If* clause.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/I6PpiR/2/)

```
(?!(?:(?=XYZ)|(?<=X)(?=YZ)|(?<=XY)(?=Z))).
```

Replacement: `+`

#### Usage

Below code auto-generated from [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/I6PpiR/2/codegen?language=java).
See code below in use [here](https://ideone.com/qm9uRt)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(?!(?:(?=XYZ)|(?<=X)(?=YZ)|(?<=XY)(?=Z))).";
final String string = "abXYxyzXYZabXasdfggXYZ";
final String subst = "+";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

---

### Results

#### Input

> abXYxyzXYZabXasdfggXYZ

#### Output

> +++++++XYZ+++++++++XYZ

---

### Explanation

- `(?!(?:(?=XYZ)|(?<=X)(?=YZ)|(?<=XY)(?=Z)))` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match
- `(?:(?=XYZ)|(?<=X)(?=YZ)|(?<=XY)(?=Z))` Match either of the following

  - `(?=XYZ)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches `XYZ` literally
  - `(?<=X)(?=YZ)` Match the following

    - `(?<=X)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is `X` literally
    - `(?=YZ)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is `YZ` literally
  - `(?<=XY)(?=Z)` Match the following

    - `(?<=XY)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is `XY` literally
    - `(?=Z)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is `Z` literally
- `.` Match any character

Comment: The regex101 link you posted has another regex in it than your post

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath thanks, I updated the regex to version 2 but forgot to update the link here. Fixed now