# How to negate the whole regex?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a regex, for example `(ma|(t){1})`. It matches `ma` and `t` and doesn't match `bla`.

I want to negate the regex, thus it must match `bla` and not `ma` and `t`, **by adding something to this regex**. I know I can write `bla`, the actual regex is however more complex.

Comment: As an aside, `{1}` is completely useless. (If you do think it provides some value, why don't you write `((m{1}a{1}){1}|(t){1}){1}`?)

Comment: what he meant to say is try {1,}

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Use negative lookaround: `(?!`*`pattern`*`)`

Positive lookarounds can be used to assert that a pattern matches. Negative lookarounds is the opposite: it's used to assert that a pattern DOES NOT match. Some flavor supports assertions; some puts limitations on lookbehind, etc.

#### Links to regular-expressions.info

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

#### See also

- [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java/)
- [Regex for all strings not containing a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971738/regex-for-all-strings-not-containing-a-string)
- [A regex to match a substring that isn’t followed by a certain other substring.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631010/a-regex-to-match-a-substring-that-isnt-followed-by-a-certain-other-substring)

#### More examples

These are attempts to come up with regex solutions to toy problems as exercises; they should be educational if you're trying to learn the various ways you can use lookarounds (nesting them, using them to capture, etc):

- [codingBat plusOut using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628534/codingbat-plusout-using-regex)
- [codingBat repeatEnd using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606214/codingbat-repeatend-using-regex)
- [codingbat wordEnds using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566482/codingbat-wordends-using-regex)

Comment: regular-expressions.info is a damn good resource for all things regex.

Comment: What all have [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) support? Does not work with `grep`.

Comment: `Pattern.compile("(?!(a.*b))").matcher("xab").matches()` should be `true`, right?

Comment: I seems like this not right, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610743/how-to-negate-any-regular-expression-in-java for a correct alternative.

Answer (score 66):

Assuming you only want to disallow strings that match the regex completely (i.e., `mmbla` is okay, but `mm` isn't), this is what you want:

```
^(?!(?:m{2}|t)$).*$
```

`(?!(?:m{2}|t)$)` is a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html); it says "starting from the current position, the next few characters are *not* `mm` or `t`, followed by the end of the string."  The start anchor (`^`) at the beginning ensures that the lookahead is applied at the beginning of the string.  If that succeeds, the `.*` goes ahead and consumes the string.

FYI, if you're using Java's `matches()` method, you don't really need the the `^` and the final `$`, but they don't do any harm.  The `$` inside the lookahead is required, though.

Comment: Most helpful part of this answer is that you have to add `.*` to the end of your regex, otherwise it will reject every string.

Comment: The `$` *inside* the negative lookahead, AND the `.*` at the end are both critical bits. As always with REs, a strong set of unit tests is absolutely critical to getting it right. This answer is 100% correct.

Comment: This only works if the match can only occur at the end of the string. If it can occur anywhere, you need `^(?!.*(?:m{2}|t)).*$` (replace `.` with `[\s\S]` for regex flavors/flags where `.` doesn't match line-breaking chars).

Answer (score 2):

```
\b(?=\w)(?!(ma|(t){1}))\b(\w*)
```

this is for the given regex.
the \b is to find word boundary.
the positive look ahead (?=\w) is here to avoid spaces.
the negative look ahead over the original regex is to prevent matches of it.
and finally the (\w*) is to catch all the words that are left.
the group that will hold the words is group 3.
the simple (?!pattern) will not work as any sub-string will match
the simple ^(?!(?:m{2}|t)$).*$ will not work as it's granularity is full lines

Answer (score 0):

The following works in JavaScript:

```js
^(?![\s\S]*ORIGINAL_REGEX_SOURCE)[\s\S]*$
```

So for example, in your case, your negated regex would be `^(?![\s\S]*(ma|(t){1}))[\s\S]*$`.

The `negate` function below can be used to convert a regex into its negated form:

```js
function negate(regex) {
    return new RegExp(
        String.raw`^(?![\s\S]*${regex.source})[\s\S]*$`,
        regex.flags,
    )
}

const tests = [
    { regex: /(ma|(t){1})/, matches: ['ma', 't'], nonMatches: ['bla'] },
    { regex: /foo/, matches: ['foo'], nonMatches: ['bar'] },
    { regex: /(foo|bar)/, matches: ['foo', 'bar'], nonMatches: ['baz'] },
    { regex: /\d{3}/, matches: ['123', '456', '999'], nonMatches: ['foo'] },
]

for (const { regex, matches, nonMatches } of tests) {
    for (const text of matches) {
        const atStart = `${text} ...`
        const atEnd = `... ${text}`
        const inMiddle = `... ${text} ...`

        check(regex.test(text), `${regex} matches ${JSON.stringify(text)}`)
        check(regex.test(atStart), `${regex} matches ${JSON.stringify(atStart)}`)
        check(regex.test(atEnd), `${regex} matches ${JSON.stringify(atEnd)}`)
        check(regex.test(inMiddle), `${regex} matches ${JSON.stringify(inMiddle)}`)

        const negated = negate(regex)

        check(!negated.test(text), `${negated} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(text)}`)
        check(!negated.test(atStart), `${negated} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(atStart)}`)
        check(!negated.test(atEnd), `${negated} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(atEnd)}`)
        check(!negated.test(inMiddle), `${negated} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(inMiddle)}`)

        const doubleNegated = negate(negated)

        check(doubleNegated.test(text), `${doubleNegated} matches ${JSON.stringify(text)}`)
        check(doubleNegated.test(atStart), `${doubleNegated} matches ${JSON.stringify(atStart)}`)
        check(doubleNegated.test(atEnd), `${doubleNegated} matches ${JSON.stringify(atEnd)}`)
        check(doubleNegated.test(inMiddle), `${doubleNegated} matches ${JSON.stringify(inMiddle)}`)
    }

    for (const text of nonMatches) {
        const atStart = `${text} ...`
        const atEnd = `... ${text}`
        const inMiddle = `... ${text} ...`

        check(!regex.test(text), `${regex} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(text)}`)
        check(!regex.test(atStart), `${regex} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(atStart)}`)
        check(!regex.test(atEnd), `${regex} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(atEnd)}`)
        check(!regex.test(inMiddle), `${regex} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(inMiddle)}`)

        const negated = negate(regex)

        check(negated.test(text), `${negated} matches ${JSON.stringify(text)}`)
        check(negated.test(atStart), `${negated} matches ${JSON.stringify(atStart)}`)
        check(negated.test(atEnd), `${negated} matches ${JSON.stringify(atEnd)}`)
        check(negated.test(inMiddle), `${negated} matches ${JSON.stringify(inMiddle)}`)

        const doubleNegated = negate(negated)

        check(!doubleNegated.test(text), `${doubleNegated} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(text)}`)
        check(!doubleNegated.test(atStart), `${doubleNegated} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(atStart)}`)
        check(!doubleNegated.test(atEnd), `${doubleNegated} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(atEnd)}`)
        check(!doubleNegated.test(inMiddle), `${doubleNegated} doesn't match ${JSON.stringify(inMiddle)}`)
    }
}

console.info('Tests passed')

function check(condition, message = 'Condition failed') {
    if (!condition) {
        throw new Error(message)
    }
    console.info(message)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This regexp math your condition:

```
^.*(?<!ma|t)$
```

Look at how it works:
https://regex101.com/r/Ryg2FX/1

Answer (score -2):

Apply this if you use laravel.

Laravel has a not_regex where field under validation must not match the given regular expression; uses the PHP `preg_match` function internally.

```
'email' => 'not_regex:/^.+$/i'
```