# Inverting a regex as a whole

Tags: regex, textpad

OK, I read through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex) and it hasn't helped me so far.

I have a regex in TextPad (not sure of its engine) like so:

```
[[:digit:]]+ \= [[:digit:]]+ \+ [[:digit:]]+
```

that finds a string such as:

```
1783635 = 1780296 + 3339
```

and I want to find everything *else*. I tried encasing the whole expression with `[^ expression ]` as the TextPad manual says to do, with no luck. I also tried `[^][ expression ]`, `^( expression )`, and `[^]( expression )`, with no luck.

From the thread above, I tried `(?! expression )`, again, with no luck.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not really possible to match *"the opposite of"* with regex. Regular expressions must *match* to succeed, they cannot *not match* and still succeed.

Depending on your exact situation (and TextPad's regex capabilities), there might be a way around this limitation.

More detail is necessary to say that for sure, though. Please provide a real-world text sample and describe what you want to do with it.

Comment: The above includes a real sample. Essentially, that string (`num = num + num`) is within a larger string, and I want to eliminate the rest of the string and extract only the part from above.

Comment: The standard practice in such a case is to match the entire string and replace it with the contents of a match group you define in your expression. How exactly that has to look in your case depends on more detail.

Comment: OK, can you exemplify what you mean? The full string looks like this: `1|dkjasad_fcase1_20110801_001.log|JWE_eggnog_fcase1_20110801_001.log|S|  0.08%|273907 = 273678 + 229`

Comment: @praguian: And that's *one line in your file* you'd like to replace with `273907 = 273678 + 229`?

Comment: Yes, just one line of many like it. I did a short-term solution of compiling the regex to find the "other" part of the line and eliminate it, but in the future the "other" part may not follow a pattern like it does today. That's why I was curious about a way to invert a match instead.

Comment: @praguian: Use `^.*\([[:digit:]]+ \= [[:digit:]]+ \+ [[:digit:]]+\).*`. The `\(...\)` creates group 1, which you can refer to as `\1` in the replacement. Search-and-replace should now remove the unwanted parts.

Comment: Worked, thank you! Is it possible to nest that functionality somehow (have a group within a group)?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I have found to do this is not with JUST regular expressions, but to use additional functionality from TextPad (bookmarks).

In this case, I needed to identify all lines that did NOT start with PHVS. So I did the following:

1. Perform "Match All" search with regular expression "^PHVS". This marked every line that started with PHVS
2. Go to Edit -> Invert Bookmarks. This marked every line that did NOT start with PHVS
3. Created a macro that pressed F2 (to go to next bookmark) and fix the line the way I needed it
4. Ran the macro to the end of the file.