# regex for not matching alpha plus numeric range

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex

```
.{19}_.{3}PDR_.{8}(ABCD|CTNE|PFRE)006[0-9][0-9].{3}_.{6}\.POC
```

a match is for example

```
NRM_0157F0680884976_598PDR_T0060000ABCD00619_00_6I1N0T.POC
```

and would like to negate the `(ABCD|CTNE|PFRE)006[0-9][0-9]`
portion such that

```
NRM_0157F0680884976_598PDR_T0060000ABCD00719_00_6I1N0T.POC
```

is a match but

```
NRM_0157F0680884976_598PDR_T0060000ABCD007192_00_6I1N0T.POC
```

or

```
NRM_0157F0680884976_598PDR_T0060000ABCD0061_00_6I1N0T.POC
```

is not (the negated part must be 9 chars long just like the non negated part for a total length of 58 chars).

Comment: _Why_ it seems _dont work_?  The first expression [seems to work](https://regex101.com/r/GLTjH3/1) and it is possible just to negate it for case 2: `!str.matches(".*(ABCD006[0-9][0-9]|CTNE006[0-9][0-9]|PFRE006[0-9][0-9]).*")`, or [negate the entire pattern using `matches()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610743/how-to-negate-any-regular-expression-in-java).  [Ideone online demo](https://ideone.com/nJEN8h)

Answer (score 4):

Consider using the following pattern:

```regex
\b(?:ABCD|CTNE|PFRE)006[0-9][0-9]\b
```

Sample Java code:

```java
String input = "Matching value is ABCD00601 but EFG123 is non matching";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:ABCD|CTNE|PFRE)006[0-9][0-9]\\b");
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found a match: " + m.group());
}
```

This prints:

```
Found a match: ABCD00601
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. Here it is my full regex .{19}_.{3}PDR_.{8}\b(?:ABCD|CTNE|PFRE)006[0-9][0-9]\b.{3}_.{6}\.POC. The following string fails but should be a match NRM_0157F0680884976_598PDR_T0060000ABCD00719_00_6I1N0T.POC

Comment: `Here it is my full regex` ... where does my answer ever suggest this regex?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to propose this expression

<del>`(ABCD|CTNE|PFRE)006\d{1,2}`</del>

where `\d{1,2}` catches any one or two digit number
that is it would get any alphanumeric values from ABCD0060~ABCD00699 or CTNE0060~CTNE00699 or PFRE0060~PFRE00699

### Edit #1:

as user @Hao Wu mentioned the above regex would also accept if its ABCD0060 which is not ideal so
this should do the job by removing 1 from the { } we can get

alphanumeric values from ABCD00600~ABCD00699 or CTNE00600~CTNE00699 or PFRE00600~PFRE00699
so the resulting regex would be

### (ABCD|CTNE|PFRE)006\d{2}

Comment: But it makes a false positive `ABCD0060`?

Comment: In the previous regex  \d{1,2} would get any digit from 0-99 so I made changes to it such that  \d{2} would now get any digit from 00-99,hope this fixes the issue for ABCD0060