# SmartGit: Log window is very slow

Tags: windows, git, smartgit

I'm using SmartGit under Windows 7 to work with a huge GIT repository (~400 branches, ~12000 tags, ~25000 commits) and opening Log window on it takes about **15 seconds**. When it is opened, toggling visibility of a branch also takes **several seconds**. Is there something I can do to speed up the Log windows responsiveness?

I've tried everything listed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25199391/261217, nothing helped. smartgit.exe consumes only around 300Mb of RAM.

I did the following actions:

1. Open SmartGit (repo is selected by default)
2. Open Log window
3. Close Log window
4. Close SmartGit

System info: 
SmartGit v6.5.2, Windows 7 x64, Intel Core i7-3770, 16Gb RAM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by too may tags in the repository. It is workarounded by disabling some tags from being loaded by SmartGit. For this, do the following:

1. Set system property `smartgit.branch.tagExcludeRegEx` to a regular expression of tags that should be disabled (available since v6.5.3, build #4165). See [documentation](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation/6.5/show?page=system-properties#system-properties) on setting system properties. You can use [negative lookaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675) to disable all except few tags.
2. Run `git pack-refs --all` to optimize access to loose tags.