# Replace wrong bbcode color regex php

Tags: php, regex, colors, bbcode

I have some problems to do a regex....

I would like to replace wrong bbcode color by a default bbcode.

```
[color=#123456]  => OK
[color=#]        => KO
[color=]         => KO
[color=#1234567] => KO
[color=#12345]   => KO
```

I started to do something but I don't understand how doing multiple tests in a regex and how match just after the = with differents mix

For exemple :

[101regex](https://regex101.com/r/xZ7aL7/1)

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Please post your regex in the question and not in a link

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in stackoverfow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to matche correct color pattern, and put default color when pattern is not matched.

```
$color = '[color=toto]';
$default_color = '[color=#123456]';
$correct_pattern = '/\[color=#\d{6}\]/';

if(!preg_match($correct_pattern, $color, $matches)) {
    $color = $default_color;
}

echo $color;
```

This code will output

```
[color=#123456]
```

If you need explanation on the regExp i can explain it on the comment

Comment: BTW, if you need to use Hexa colors, and not only decimal colors, you will have to replace the "\d" in the regExp by  "[0-9A-F]"

Comment: first thank for your rapidity, Unfortunately, I must replacing in complexe text. I can't match one per one all the bbcode code.

Comment: So you can use only the regExp '/\[color=#\d{6}\]/' or '/\[color=#[0-9A-F]{6}\]/' depending on your need

Answer (score 0):

I would like to complete his pattern by including the hexa case and /i argument for the regex, making the pattern:

```
$pattern = "/\[color=#[0-9a-f]{6}\]/i";
```

edit: @sylvain: *"I must replacing in complexe text. I can't match one per one all the bbcode code"*

Go for [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) then.

Comment: Yeah i was wondering too, maybe  "/\[color=#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}\]/i" with Upper Case letter be good too

Comment: I would like the opposite :p , I need to remplace all the wrong bbcode and not match the good one.

Comment: Use negative look arounds then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex

Answer (score 0):

Arh .. I seen the ambiguity of my question .....

I would like the wrong bbcode is match by the regex. In fact all the KO item will be replace after = by #000000

```
 [color=#123456]  => KO
 [color=#]        => matched
 [color=]         => matched
 [color=#1234567] => matched
 [color=#12345]   => matched
 [color=lightgray]   => matched
```