# Problems to negate regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have several regex patterns and i have to negate them all, so i am trying to build somo generic regex negate, something like /^(anypattern)/ but I am having troubles..

for example, I have this text: `zzzzzAAAAA@AAAA_AAAzzzzzzAAAAA@AAAA.AAAggggggAAAAA@AAA.AAAooooooooo`

and this pattern: `[A-Z]+@[A-Z]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}`, I need something to negate this. I would get the an array with the following matches:

```
zzzzzAAAAA@AAAA_AAAzzzzzz , gggggg , ooooooooo
```

Note that `AAAAA@AAAA_AAA` was included only because this have a _ instead a dot

my regex are all simple, dont having any of these especial caracteres: \s,\t,\r,\n,\v,\f,\b,etc..

I tryed to solve it with negative lookarounds but without success

Comment: Please define "negate".

Comment: Is it the negation you want: `[^A-Z]+[^@][^A-Z]+[^.][^A-Z]{2,4}`? https://regex101.com/r/uT3pQ2/1.

Comment: negate: get everything that the pattern dont match @JDB

Comment: i tryed this `(?!([A-Z]+@[A-Z]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}))` @garis

Comment: Use `!regexp.test(str)`.

Comment: also: `gggggg` is matched in your current regex.

Comment: @stribizhev your solution dont match `zzzzzAAAAA@AAAA_AAAzzzzzz`

Comment: a possible way i think is split the string with the original regex, but i would be using a programming language, somthing i dont want

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to negate the whole regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex)

Comment: @leandromoh - Use negative lookahead.

Comment: @JDB isnt what I tryied negative lookahead? `(?!([A-Z]+@[A-Z]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a split with the regex exactly as you have it?

```
var input = "zzzzzAAAAA@AAAA_AAAzzzzzzAAAAA@AAAA.AAAggggggAAAAA@AAA.AAAooooooooo"
var output = input.split(/[A-Z]+@[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/)
console.log(output)

// outputs ["zzzzzAAAAA@AAAA_AAAzzzzzz", "gggggg", "ooooooooo"]
```

However, you may need to clean out empty elements, consider

```
var input = "AAAAA@AAAA.AAAzzzzzAAAAA@AAAA_AAAzzzzzzAAAAA@AAAA.AAAggggggAAAAA@AAA.AAAooooooooo"
var output = input.split(/[A-Z]+@[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/)
console.log(output)
// outputs ["", "zzzzzAAAAA@AAAA_AAAzzzzzz", "gggggg", "ooooooooo"]
```

After the setting the output variable, you can add this courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843625/3917091)

```
output = output.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined && n.length})
// which outputs ["zzzzzAAAAA@AAAA_AAAzzzzzz", "gggggg", "ooooooooo"]
```

Comment: @cfquerymaram This is exacty what I want, but is there a way to do it only with regex?