# How can I push regex matches to array in java?

Tags: java, regex

I've currently got a string, of which I want to use certain parts. With these parts I want to do various things, like pushing them to an array or showing them in a text area.

Fist I try to split method. It delete my regex matches and prints other part of string. I want to delete other part and print the regex match.

How can I do this?

For example:
There are lot of youtube links like this

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJuoXM7G322&list=PLRfAW_jVDn06M7qxHIwlowgLY3Io1pG6z&index=7
```

I want to take only simple video link with this expression

```
"https:\\/\\/www.youtube.com\\/watch\\?v=.{11}"
```

when I use this code :

```
    String ytLink = linkArea.getText();
    String regexp = "https:\\/\\/www.youtube.com\\/watch\\?v=.{11}";
    String[] tokenVal;
    tokenVal = ytLink.split(regexp);

    System.out.println("Count of Links : "+tokenVal.length);

    for (String t : tokenVal) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

It prints

```
"&list=PLRfAW_jVDn06M7qxHIwlowgLY3Io1pG6z&index=7"
```

I want to output be like this:

```
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SATL2mTfZO0"
```

Comment: Can you please post at least one example so that we can go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "when I Right this code :"

You are *splitting* the string with that regular expression, which is not the correct tool for the job.

It is dividing your example string into:

```
""                                                 // The bit before the separator.
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJuoXM7G322"      // The separator
"&list=PLRfAW_jVDn06M7qxHIwlowgLY3Io1pG6z&index=7" // The bit after the separator
```

but then discarding the separator, so you'd get back a 2-element array containing:

```
""                                                 // The bit before the separator.
"&list=PLRfAW_jVDn06M7qxHIwlowgLY3Io1pG6z&index=7" // The bit after the separator
```

If you want to get the thing that *matches* the regex, you'd need to use `Pattern` and `Matcher`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("https:\\/\\/www.youtube.com\\/watch\\?v=.{11}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ytLink);
if (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

(I don't entirely trust your escaped backslashes in your regular expression; however the pattern is not really important to the principle)

Comment: it works for 1 link. If it can work for many links. it will OK.

Comment: Change `if` to `while`. Read the documentation for `java.util.regex.Matcher`.

Comment: OK every thing is ok. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can negate your regex using the negative lookaround: `(?!pattern)`

See also : [How to negate the whole regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex)