# regex exclude for group

Tags: regex

This is a regex that matches everything i want to exclude, which is words like abba, trillion etc.

```
[a-z]*([a-z])([a-z])\2\1[a-z]*
```

Is there something like [^] which i can use in this situation?

Comment: post some valid and invalid examples..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to negate the whole regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex)

Comment: The [*How to negate the whole regex*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex) post explains the negative lookahead technique and an example of how to exclude a whole string match, but unfortunately, not how to exclude matching *whole words*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?![a-z]*([a-z])([a-z])\2\1[a-z]*\b)[a-z]+\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ4wW4/2) (I think you need a case-insensitive modifier with this regex.)

Since you want to match words only, you need to use `\b` word boundary, and to exclude specific words, you need to use a *negative lookahead* anchored to the leading word boundary.