# Using regex in notepad ++ to extract text and if not found

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a large number of txt-files and aim to extract a certain piece of text out of each of them. I managed to this for most of my files using regex in notepad. I just use find-and-replace for all files in a folder using a pretty elaborate regex:

Find:

```
.*(pretty elaborate regex).*
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

This works great. However, some of my documents do not contain the specific piece of text I am looking for. Notepad will leave these documents unchanged. How can I let it put a text in these documents which says for example: "no_match_found"

Thanks for you help!
Andreas

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the whole document in those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy with the Boost conditional replacement pattern. Add a `|(.*)` alternative branch to your regex (make sure the *`.` matches newline* is ON) and use `(?1$1:NO_MATCH_FOUND)` pattern that will eaither insert the Group 1 value, or will just replace the whole document with the literal text `NO_MATCH_FOUND`.

Here is an example of what happens to a document having no match:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post will help you: [How to negate the whole regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex)

> Use negative lookaround: (?!pattern)

You can just match for the negated regex and place the text then