# Remove charterers which are not matching to dynamic regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to remove all the characters which are not matching to a given regex expression. I know we can invert the regex using ^. But in my case the regex expression varies for each input. I am trying to achieve a generic solution. Is there any way, we can invert any dynamic regex expression ? or any other option to remove non matching characters ?

The following snippet gives an idea, what I am trying to achieve.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[check]').on('input',(function(){  
    //validate the input value with regex and remove none matching charectors
  }))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="string" check='(\d|[a-z])'/>
```

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: Did you try anything? post your code. What exactly you want?

Comment: @torazaburo - added a sample code

Comment: Consider ways to use the `pattern` attribute.

Comment: Pattern attribute only does the validation. But the user will be still able to type

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? [How to negate the whole regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex)

For example, if you were looking for:

```
[abc]{3}
```

Which would match `cab` but not `dad`, obviously you cannot just say:

```
[^abc]{3}    # Does not work!
```

Since that would not match `cab` or `dad`.

Instead, you could do something like this:

```
^(?![abc]{3})
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/CvvPt0/2 for no capture (my example).
Example 2: https://regex101.com/r/CvvPt0/3 to capture 3 characters too.

Note that I don't know how you want to implement it, but I can modify it a little if you share with us.