# How do I negate an exact match in regex?

Tags: regex

If the user enters exactly "null", I want the regex match to fail.
Entering "xxxnullxxx" is ok however.

The following regex rejects "null" but it also rejects any string containing "null", which I don't want.

```
^(?!.*null).*$
```

Comment: Why do you need regex? Just do `if ("null".equals(str))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to negate the whole regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex)

Comment: @4castle there are plenty of cases where the validation API is regex (only)

Comment: @4castle: I'm using a JavaScript library which accepts regex to validate form fields.

Answer (score 4):

Add `$` and remove `.*` from the look ahead:

```
^(?!null$).*
```

The trailing `$` isn't needed.

Comment: I was able to get it working after using a variation of your answer:.    ^(?!null$)     without the trailing .$.

Comment: @jim if you mean `^(?!null).*`, that would match `"nullify"` etc

Comment: I meant `^(?!null$)`. I only want to ignore the exact match "null".

Answer (score 1):

This will match everything except for null: `^(?!(?:null)$).*$` I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637899/1768033).