# find any text except text with this pattern with regex

Tags: regex

I want to find any text except text with this pattern. In other word, How can I inverse select with regex ?

```
\\+?(9892\\d{8})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to negate the whole regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex)

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?=\w)(?!\+?(9892\d{8}))\b(\w*)
```

this is for the given regex.
the \b is to find word boundary.
the positive look ahead (?=\w) is here to avoid spaces.
the negative look ahead over the original regex is to prevent matches of it.
and finally the (\w*) is to catch all the words that are left.
the group that will hold the words is group 2.