# How to split a string using the re module by identifying the structure of the token

Tags: python, regex

I understand that when I want to use the re module in Python and the split() method, I need to provide the pattern where I want to break the string (i.e. at white spaces, I would use a pattern like this `pattern = re.compile('\\s+')`).

But for more complex cases, where I have a string with a pattern which looks like this:

```
'letters<space>letters<space>numbers<space>...repeat...'
```

how should I write the regex to split at every repetition? I tried to use the negate of the expression that matches the string exactly until the repetition, like is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex), but Python throws an error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you be more concise?, What's your expected output?

Comment: getting all the substrings that look like:

'letters<space>letters<space>numbers<space>', 'letters<space>letters<space>numbers<space>', etc.

Comment: "An error": I am sure Python says much more than that. Add the code that produced the error and the resulting traceback.

Comment: Plus it still isn't too clear what you ask. Do you need any kind of repetition? Then it isn't really a `re.split`, since you don't have any meaningful delimiter.

Comment: _I tried to use the negate of the expression that matches the string exactly until the repetition, like is suggested here, but Python throws an error._ **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].** Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving the example string:

```
text = 'aaaaa 12345 aaaaa bbbbb 12345 bbbbb ccccc 12345 ccccc'
```

instead you use `re.split()` maybe you can use `re.findall()`:

```
re.findall(r'\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+', text)
# output: ['aaaaa 12345 aaaaa', 'bbbbb 12345 bbbbb', 'ccccc 12345 ccccc']
```

If you want to use `re.split()` anyway you can put it into a group and then use a generator to clean the spaces:

```
splitted = re.split(r'(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)', text)
#output: ['', 'aaaaa 12345 aaaaa', ' ', 'bbbbb 12345 bbbbb', ' ', 'ccccc 12345 ccccc', '']

[ele for ele in splitted if ele.strip()]
#output: ['aaaaa 12345 aaaaa', 'bbbbb 12345 bbbbb', 'ccccc 12345 ccccc']
```

Answer (score 1):

Given I understood the question correctly, this could be a way to split the strings:

```
In [298]: s                                                                                                           
Out[298]: 'lettersone letterstwo 12 lettersthree lettersfour 34'

In [299]: re.findall(r'(?:\w+ \w+ \d+)', s)                                                                           
Out[299]: ['lettersone letterstwo 12', 'lettersthree lettersfour 34']
```